# Bootstrap Modal Element's Height Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to display an Image in a Bootstrap Modal by using a div.
Assume this:

```
<div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <div class = 'img-modal'>
                    <img   src="<?php echo base_url().$articulo[0]->rutaImagen;?>">
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

The problem is that when the Modal opens, I want to center the Image, but the Image's Height and Width are, according to jquery/Javascript, 0. My Idea was to make the Image's position relative, and then use the Height/2 and Width/2 in order to center it in the div, but as I mentioned before, Height and Width appear to be 0.

My question is: is there some workaround so that Height/Width appear correctly?

Thanks in Advance,
Hope it's clear enough now.

NOTE: The Modal is working fine. Though I'm only showing the Body part, the rest is there.

Comment: Are you trying to show your image in the modal? Your question isn't clear.

Comment: Yeah, and sorry about that.. let me fix it

Comment: No problem, You might wanna include some code, or people will down vote you.

Comment: Tried to make the question clearer and Included some code. Hope it helps

Comment: OK, so are you trying to center your Image in the Modal, or relative to the page?

Comment: If you show the image out of the modal does it have height/width? If you place text in the modal does it show?

Comment: As far as centering the image, give the `col-*` div an offset add class `col-md-offset-3`

Comment: For panel elements (In the Modal I'm only using images and Panels) I get Height = -2. Check it out: http://prntscr.com/5m9emx and Typhomism, Yes, If I show the image outside the Modal it DOES have Width/Height

Comment: Forgot to mention: My modal is loaded through AJAX. In the success function is where I work with the Height/Width.

Comment: I can't see the screenshot at the moment as works barracuda filter is too damn strict. is there any change you can post the relevant jquery/ajax?

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/lrojas94/181nk9bL/ I commented out the modal code, but that's what the request returns. The Div located the top (ModalPlaceholder), is where I put the modal information. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around a bit, it seems that, since a modal is hidden until you decide to show it, all values all 0. I used the 'shown.bs.modal' event to center and show the image correctly and it is now working flawlessly. I'm sorry I was a bother to everyone. I did try this before and it didn't work... I don't even know why it's working right now, but I'm happy it did.

Thanks to @Typhorism and @Joe Swindell for trying to help me :)